# Ag-Grid - Master Detail Checkbox Row Selection Angular Example?

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I am using an angular ag-grid where I am trying to achieve master detail checkbox selection but there is not great examples even on their site on how to achieve this.   I have been able to get when selecting the master parent row selected the detail rows all get selected successfully from another example on this site.   I am having trouble going the other way when a detail rows all selected or the detail parent header is selected to select the master node.

Example of the master selecting the detail rows:

```
public onRowSelected(event: any) {
    if (event.node.master && event.node.expanded) {
      const gridDetailGridInfo = event.api.getDetailGridInfo(
        event.node.detailNode.id
      );
      if (gridDetailGridInfo && gridDetailGridInfo.api) {
        gridDetailGridInfo.api.forEachNode((node: any) => {
          node.setSelected(event.node.selected);
        });
      }
    }
  }
```

I am now trying in the detail grid onrowselected to access the master row if all detail rows selected then check the master node checkbox.  This code gets into the onrowselected but I can't see how to get to the master node.

Example:

```
const detailGridOptions: GridOptions = {
      columnDefs: this.detailGridColDefs,
      rowSelection: "multiple",
      onRowSelected: (params) => {
        console.log(params);
      },
    };
```

Comment: Any luck with this? I'm trying to do the same thing right now.